# How to convert from HBITMAP to .NET's Bitmap class?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am using some C++ code that employs the `CreateDIBSection` function to create a bitmap and return a `HBITMAP` handle. What is the best way of getting this information into my .NET assembly?

Answer (score 6):

The static method [Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: But do I have to release the bitmap from C#?

Comment: Yes, you can call Dispose(): using (Bitmap bmp = Image.FromHbitmap(hbitmap)) { /* Do some work with the bitmap */ }

Comment: I found I needed to call DeleteObject to get rid of the gdi bitmap. The managed bitmap is a copy so it's safe to call right away. [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried marshalling the byte array for your bitmap across, loading it into a MemoryStream and then using that stream to construct a Bitmap class?